# Does PHP allow class functions & properties to share the same name?

Tags: php

An old colleague of mine wrote this in our code:

```
public function paginate() {
    return $this->paginate;
}
```

And I was wondering: does this return the function paginate() or the class property $paginate?

I'm guessing the latter, but it is strange that I haven't found any information on this subject.

Comment: Why you didn't tried yourself.

Comment: Because PHP have many hidden/auto/magic behaviors that could be missed by simple tests!

Answer (score 6):

That returns the class property `$paginate`.

If it was `return $this->someName();`

then it returns function `someName()`.

Answer (score 3):

The brackets after a function call in PHP aren't optional, and ordinary methods and functions are not "first class objects" (they can't be manipulated as variables in their own right, as for instance, in JavaScript).

Thus there is no ambiguity, since `$this->paginate();` must be a function call, and `$this->paginate;` must be a variable reference.

However, it is not particularly good practice, and editors, IDEs, etc, will probably highlight it as a warning.

Common practice is for functions and methods to begin with a verb (what it *does*), and property names to be a noun (what it *is*). So the property should probably be ["pagination"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pagination#English), and the method either ["paginate"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paginate) (take the data and create some pagination), or "getPagination" (return the "pagination" property).

Answer (score 1):

Return an object property:

```
$this->paginate;
```

vs

Cause an object method to run (function in a class is termed a method)

```
$this->paginate();
```

Answer (score 0):

It will return the `$paginate` property of the class that the function belongs to or ihnerits from another class, if it is declared as `public`.